# Changing axis on scatterplot to fixed intervals involving time

Tags: python, datetime, time, scatter

I have following code. my problem is I want to set the range of the y axis from 0:00 to 12:00 and have it equally spaced in increments of one. e.g. 0:00, 1:00, 2:00 etc. Any suggestions how I would go about doing this?

Also I also want to get rid of the extra :00 at the end of each number. As of right now it reads 00:00:00, 01:00:00 and so on when I only want it to read 0:00, 1:00 any ideas how I can go about doing this? here is the code I have so far.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import datetime

    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', header=None)
    print (data)




    ints = data[data[1]=='INT']
    exts = data[data[1]=='EXT']



    int_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) for t in ints[4]]
    ext_times = [datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')) for t in exts[4]]
    int_dist = [d for d in ints[3]]
    ext_dist = [d for d in exts[3]]



    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(int_dist, int_times, c='red', s=80)
    ax.scatter(ext_dist, ext_times, c='blue', s=80)

    plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
    plt.xlabel('Distance')
    plt.ylim(0,45000)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its possible to generate a list of time having only the minute and second. You need to change the format to '%M:%S'.

Next you need to change the labels using the plt.xticks(). I changed for x axis.

Here is a sample

```
start = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(0, 0))
axis_times = []
y_values = []
i = 0
while i<9:
    start += timedelta(seconds=7)
    axis_times.append(start.strftime("%M:%S"))
    y_values.append(i)
    i+=1



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(range(len(axis_times)), y_values, c='red', s=80)
ax.scatter(range(len(axis_times)), y_values, c='blue', s=20)

plt.legend(['INT', 'EXT'], loc=4)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.xticks(range(len(axis_times)), axis_times, size='small')

plt.show()
```

Comment: when i change it to '%M:%S'  it now reads 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00 so it still shows the hours as 00. Is there a way so that i just reads 00:00, 01:00, 02:00?

Comment: Well you can further look at the data that you are importing and check how are you converting the format to your desired type

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify ticks to whatever you need. I can't run your example without the csv data but you can do,

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import datetime

#Some arbitrary data
x = np.linspace(0.,12.,100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x)+6.)

#Set number of ticks to 12
ax.set_yticks(range(13))

#Relabel the ticks as needed
locs, labels = plt.yticks()
new_labels = [str(time) + ":00" for time in range(0,13)]
plt.yticks(locs, new_labels)

plt.show()
```

You can replace the new labels using datetime values or formatted strings which you obtain from you data (e.g. convert to string and remove the last 0)...